# Set scope for data-ng-init IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tried this:

```
<label id="labelPersonalInformationExtra" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span id="inputLabel" class="input-label">Gender</span>
    <select data-ng-init= "gender=gender[{{y}}]" data-ng-model="gender" data-ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders"></select>
    </select>
    </label>
```

but i get this error

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{'
>   invalid key at column 17 of the expression [gender3=gender[{{y}}]]
>   starting at [{y}}]].

y 
is a number I want to set at the start. It would vary thats why i need to do it this way. How can I fix the syntax to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the interpolation braces

```
data-ng-init= "gender=gender[y]"
```

Comment: suggestion to avoid usage of `ng-init` would be great, if you can add it :)

Comment: @charlietfl simply writing [y] doesn't work. It shows blank. Just fyi y is $scope.y=0;

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of `{{}}` inside `ng-init` directive, it should be `data-ng-init= "gender=genders[y]"`.

Though you shouldn't be using [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) in application anywhere, you can initialize the same from controller

```
$scope.gender= $scope.genders[$scope.y]
```

Comment: Im sorry I am new to this, im not sure i understand exactly.

Comment: @noor though it should be `genders` instead of `gender`

Comment: @noor may I know what is `y`? check [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UZQFF9EDudpiOJrtX1sA?p=preview)

Comment: y is a number. I plan on changing it for future use that is why I cannot hard code it.

Comment: You can but do it inside a controller & then have it inside `$scope` if you want to modify it from html